# Is there a possibility to use cross-platform-solutions additionally or integrate their api

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cross-platform, smartphone

In the recent weeks I have been busy with the issue of cross-platform development. That starts with the problem that I had the feeding to write a wrapper for the communication-API of MoSync (I don´t knew this SDK and others for cpd before). It should be used in our Java environment for instance to easy create a bluetooth-connection to different phones and so on.

For me the other question is now, how I can use such SDKs like MoSync, Titanium and others in a existing project? In my opinion it is not possible. Either you develop nativ or with a cpd-framework.

I would also be interested in when do you recommend this frameworks (I know already that there are some other threads about this). I personally would say that there isn´t a great future for this SDKs because of technical drawbacks and dependencies. In addition, the market for cross-platform solutions (hybrid, interpreted, cross-compiler) is at least as fragmented as the market for mobile operating systems themselves

What are your experiences?

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Cross-platform implementations of any type, on mobile or anywhere, are primarily to reduce the time to market. That statement may look like oversimplified, but it more or less holds true. So, the ideal situation to use it would be to have an application/game that maybe, uses the common denominator of features across the smartphones, which could include touch, a decent UI, the network, maybe the accelerometer in some cases LBS. So, you land on multiple phones in quicker time and reduced development cost.

If you are looking to utilize a lot of hardware specific features, then we land into what's commonly known as the unknown territories. Then you have to do what people always do, gather more information about the landscape of phones to target and see if the "chosen framework" has the power to dish out the features on those platforms. In this case, you cant possibly deploy one off-the-shelf.